# Bootstrap Collapse component in table jumping issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Collapse component in a table, everything works perfectly, but the component '**jumps**' when I expand/collapse it, which randomly changed the width of table. Please see JSFiddle below for detail.

I've read other posts on Stackoverflow and I've already set `margin:0; padding:0;`, but still not working, does anyone have ideas what I missed?

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/edward0524/uewvc5oq/3/

Comment: You have not set any width restrictions on the columns, or on the content of column A.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thank you!  Added  `style="width:100%"` to `<th scope="col" style="width:100%">Col A</th>` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define width to your column, add width:100% to < th >.